# Firefox developer cannot find chrome://ubufox/locale/ubufox.properties

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm getting an error when I open my firefox developer edition browser in Windows 10, which is that it cannot find chrome://ubufox/locale/ubufox.properties.

I suppose the reason is that I have installed firefox developer on my D drive (because I have a small ssd drive for C)

So I would like to first off know where I should look for the file Firefox is expecting, and how I can configure Firefox developer to find that file.